# How to get a query to return my mock object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, stubbing

If in my RSpec test I have

```
foo = mock_model(Foo, id: 1)
```

& my code runs

```
Foo.where(id: 1)
```

My code will always fail as the `mock_model` `foo` never gets to belong to the Foo collection, e.g.

```
Foo.count # => 0
```

If I run `foo.instance_of?(Foo)` I get `true` so the behaviour is right. What am I missing? I'd like to rely on true mocks & not have to rely on FactoryGirl or instantiate an object of Foo itself.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, well done on not using FactoryGirl. Your tests will become faster as you are reducing the number of times your tests hit your database. But this approach will need perseverance.

Now, once you use mock_model you will need to stub all of the methods that are called on your mock.

This means you will not be able to call Foo.where(id: 1), as this is a model object that will not contain your newly created foo. Remember foo is a mocked object, which is not written to your database.

So the 'anomaly' you are getting is not an anomaly. It is telling you that your mocked object foo, has a form Foo, which of course it does. But your mock is not saved to the database. Hence Foo.count returns 0.

To finish your test you need to finish off your assertion by saying something along these lines

`allow(Foo).to receive(where).with(id: 1).and_return(foo)`

I hope this helps